# pivot_table error - InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: pandas

The above error is being raised from a pivot_table operation for a variable set to be the column grouping (if it matters, it's failing in the format.py module)

```
/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py in __call__(self, num)
   2477         sign = 1
   2478 
-> 2479         if dnum < 0:  # pragma: no cover
   2480             sign = -1
   2481             dnum = -dnum
```

(Pandas v17.1)

If I create random values for the 'problem' variable via numpy there is no error.

Whilst I doubt it's an edge case for the pivot_table function, I can't figure out what might be causing the problem on the data side:

i) The variable is the first integer from a modest sized sequence of integers (eg 2 from 246)  (via df.var.str[0]).

ii) pd.unique(df.var) returns the expected 1-9 values

iii) There are no NaNs: notnull(df.var).all() returns True

iv) The dtype is int64 (or if the integer is cast as a string - or set to  label these alternatives still fail with the same error)

v) a period index is used - and that forms the index for pivot table.

vi) the aggregation is 'count'

Creating a another variable with random values with those characteristics (1-9 values from from numpy's random.randint) - the pivot_table call works. If I cast it as a string, or use labels, it still works.

Likewise, I've been playing with the data set for a while - usually on some other position in the sequence without issue.  But today - the first place is causing a problem.

Possibly, it's a data issue - but why doesn't pivot_table return empty cells or NaNs, rather than failing at that point.

But I'm at a loss after a day exploring.

any thoughts on why the above error is being raised would be much appreciated (as it'll help me track down the data issue if that is the case).

thanks
Chris

Comment: Can you provide a small, self-contained example demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to reset pandas formatting options by

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', None)
```

**further details**

I had encoutered same problem. As a workaround you can also filter dataframe that is pivoted to avoid NaNs in result.

My problem is related to use of `pd.set_eng_float_format(2, True)`. Without this all pivots works well.

Comment: much thanks - I was pulled off this problem after posting - and returned to it today. 

And I can confirm same issue caused the problem for formatting the pivottable: `pd.set_eng_float_format(accuracy=1, use_eng_prefix=True)`